# Валидация свойств модели в SelectedModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, валидация, model

Есть 2 SelectedModels:

```
SelectedCanvas
{
public CanvasModel {get;set;}
}

SelectedImage
{
public ImageModel {get;set;}
}
```

, каждая из которых содержит свою модель:

```
CanvasModel
{
public double CanvasWidth {get;set;}
public double CanvasHeight {get;set;}
}

ImageModel
{
public double X {get;set;}
public double Y {get;set;}
}
```

Свойства выбранной CanvasModel(Width, Height) должны накладывать ограничения на свойства выбранной ImageModel(X,Y), на которую байндятся несколько View-моделей.

Вопрос: как правильнее организовать валидацию, с учетом того, что прямой связи между выбранными моделями нет?

Comment: У вас есть классы SelectedCanvas и SelectedImage? Почему это не свойства ViewModel?

Comment: SelectedCanvas и SelectedImage это модели, которые инжектятся и шарятся на несколько ViewModels.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что у вас есть по крайней мере две ViewModel, которые не знают друг о друге? Причем свойство ImageModel одной зависит от свойства  CanvasModel другой.

Comment: Все верно, ViewModels не зависят друг от друга и знают только о выбранном на данный момент CanvasModel и ImageModel.

Comment: Вы уверены в правильности выбранного подхода? Может стоит его пересмотреть?

Comment: Этот подход уже результат пересмотра, который снял массу проблем: компоненты независимы, легко тестируемы, хорошая читаемость и простое расширение функционала. Буду рад, если предложите более правильный подход.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Расскажу как был решен вопрос, может кому-то пригодится.

1. Был выделен интерфейс

   ```
   IBounds
   {
   Width { get;set; }
   Height { get;set; }
   }
   ```
2. от него унаследован `CanvasModel`
3. в `ImageModel` было добавлено св-во:

   ```
   ImageModel
   {
   IBounds Bounds { get; set; }
   }
   ```
4. При добавлении новой `ImageModel` св-ву `Bounds` присваивается `SelectedCanvas.CanvasModel`
5. Валидация реализуется в `ImageModel`.

Comment: А если в какой-то момент времени изменится `SelectedCanvas` как Ваши `ImageModel` узнают об этом и выполнят валидацию?

Comment: В моём случае CanvasModel содержит коллекцию ImageModel и Bounds присваивается при добавлении в коллекцию.

Answer (score 1):

Ориентируясь на

> Свойства выбранной CanvasModel(Width, Height) должны накладывать ограничения на свойства выбранной ImageModel(X,Y), на которую байндятся несколько View-моделей.

я бы сделал как-нибудь так

```
public class MainVM : BaseVM
{

private CanvasVM _selectedCanvas;

public CanvasVM SelectedCanvas 
{ 
    get { return _selectedCanvas; }
    set
    {
        // Тут, по-хорошему, тоже надо проверять на доспустимость выбора, если SelectedImage != null
        _selectedCanvas = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedCanvas");
    }
}

private ImageVM _selectedImage;

public ImageVM SelectedImage
{
    get { return _selectedImage; }
    set
    {
        if (/*Проверка на допустимость выбора с учетом SelectedCanvas*/)
        {
            // Ошибка, недопустимое значение
            throw new ArgumentException("Такой Image не подойдет!");
        }
        _selectedImage = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedImage");
    }
}
}
```

Где

`ImageVM` - ViewModel для `ImageModel`

`CanvasVM` - ViewModel для `CanvasModel`

`MainVM` - ViewModel, в которой происходит работа по установке `SelectedImage` и `SelectedCanvas`.

А `View` я бы привязывал к `MainVM`.

Comment: Не совсем так. Ограничений на выбор ImageModel нет, есть ограничения на св-ва ImageModel. ImageModel.X не может быть больше CanvasModel.Width.

Comment: Ну и проверяйте его при изменении `SelectedCanvas` и `SelectedImage`. Вы вольны выполнить любую проверку на основе имеющихся данных

Comment: Такая проверка ничего не даст, т.к. св-ва меняются после изменений SelectedCanvas и SelectedImage. Да, и у SelectedCanvas нет ссылки на SelectedImage, так же как и у SelectedImage нет на SelectedCanvas.

Comment: Делайте все изменения `SelectedCanvas` и `SelectedImage` **только** через `MainVM`, тогда проверка будет выполняться всегда

Comment: Доступ к выбранным моделям имеют несколько VM, в этом весь смысл SelectedModel.

Comment: Ну а в чем проблема давать им экземпляр `MainVM`? Пусть они через нее к `SelectedCanvas` и `SelectedImage` доступ получают